# What is the maximum number of quadrants in $n$ dimensional space that a $k$ dimensional hyperplane can pass through?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Assume that the hyperplane passes through the origin i.e. it is the span of some $k$ linearly independent vectors in $n$-space.

For example, for $n,k = 2,1,$ we have a line in the 2d plane passing through the origin, so the answer is 2. For $n,k=3,2$, it is 6.

In fact, I have proven that $F(n,n-1)=F(n-1,n-2)+2^{n-1}$. This follows by considering the $(n-1)$-subspace for which one of the coordinates is 0. The intersection of this subspace with the hyperplane is an $n-2$ dimensional hyperplane which passes through the origin and $F(n-1,n-2)$ quadrants of the subspace. For each quadrant, the original hyperplane will at maximum pass through two corresponding quadrants of the $n$-space. And for each quadrant it does not pass through, the original can pass through at most one quadrant. The recurrence follows.

But I am unable to extend this proof to general $k$, or even $n-2$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It is worth noting that your problem is equivalent to the following one:

> What is the maximal number of cells an arrangement of $n$ hyperplanes can split $\mathbb R^k$ into?

Here, I use "hyperplane" as in "codimension $1$ subspace". More usefully, suppose we represent such an arrangement as a number of non-zero maps $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ with $f_i:\mathbb R^k\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and the hyperplanes in the arrangement being the kernel of each map. A *cell* is then a subset of $\mathbb R^k$ with a specified sign for each $f_i$ - for instance, the set where each $f_i$ is positive is a cell (if non-empty).

To get from this reduced problem to yours, define a map $f:\mathbb R^k\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ as
$$f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots,f_n(x)).$$
We find that $f(\mathbb R^k)$ is a subspace of dimension $k$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that the image of any cell is exactly the intersection of that hyperplane with some quadrant and the preimage of a quadrant is exactly a cell. Thus there are equally many cells in the arrangement as there are quadrants intersected by the associated subspace.

To get from your problem to the reduced one, let $S$ be the subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ in question and $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be the inclusion of $S$ into the space $\mathbb R^n$. Define $f_i(x)$ to be the $i^{th}$ coordinate of $f(x)$ and note that these are linear maps. Moreover, which quadrant some $x\in S$ is in is determined by the signs of the $f_i$ and the intersection of the hyperplane $x_i=0$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with $S$ is precisely the kernel of $f_i$ by definition. Otherwise said, the intersection of a quadrant with $S$ is precisely a cell in the arrangement of hyperplanes given by $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ in $S$.

I think it is easier to get a hold on this modified problem. In particular, suppose we have an arrangement of $n$ hyperplanes $H_1,\ldots,H_n$ in $\mathbb R^k$ and add some hyperplane $H'$ to it and wish to know how many more cells were created by this hyperplane. Well, we get more cells exactly when $H'$ splits an existing cell into two. We can find how many times $H'$ does that by considering the cells induced in $H'$ by the hyperplanes $H_1\cap H',\ldots,H_n\cap H'$. That is, the new cells in $\mathbb R^k$ created by adding the hyperplane $H'$ correspond to the cells in a $k-1$ dimensional arrangement of $n$ hyperplanes.

Letting $F(n,k)$ be the maximal number of cells in such an arrangement, we get the relation
$$F(n+1,k)\leq F(n,k) + F(n,k-1).$$
One can find, more strongly, that if you choose a set of $n$ hyperplanes such that the intersection of any $n+1$ of them is a point (i.e. so that they are in general position) that this bound is obtained (this may be proved by induction), thus
$$F(n+1,k)=F(n,k) + F(n,k-1).$$
Then, we have initial conditions
$$F(1,k)=2$$
$$F(n,1)=2.$$
These uniquely specify the function. One may use this to prove, by induction, the formula:
$$F(n,k)=2\sum_{d=0}^{k-1}{n-1 \choose d}.$$

Comment: As an aside, if you want to know *which* quadrants can be intersected, one finds that the "signatures" of the quadrants intersected are exactly the maximal vectors of a (realizable) [oriented matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_matroid). This is something that has interested me immensely as of late.

Comment: Why do you claim $F(1,k)=2$? I think $F(n,0)=0$ because a zero-dimensional subspace doesn't intersect (the interior of) any quadrant. Similarly $F(n,n)=2^n$ because $\mathbb R^n$ intersects each of its $2^n$ quadrants.

Comment: Ah, on further thought I guess you are restricting to $k\geq1$. In this case I agree. I was using a different boundary because the original problem doesn't make sense for $k>n$.

Comment: Can you let me know some references to know which quadrants can be intersected? I am studying 'oriented matroid' and 'hyperplane arrangement'. But, I still don't have a sense for how I approach the question. @Milo

Comment: @kswim Oriented matroids are not particularly necessary to solving this problem; it's worth considering the $3$-dimensional case, for this problem - which can be somewhat simplified by interchanging "planes in $\mathbb R^3$" for "affine lines in $\mathbb R^2$". However, for more general questions about which quadrants are intersected, oriented matroid theory is a good choice - the canonical reference is Oriented Matroids by Bjorner, Las Vergnas et. al, which discusses hyperplane arrangements at some length in its first two chapters.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! @Milo

Comment: According to [Cover (1965)](http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/paper2.pdf) in the last formula the sum should stop at $k-1$, which makes sense for small number examples like $F(3,2)$ has to be $6$, so the sum has to end at $1$.

Comment: @McLawrence Oops, yes you are right - I corrected the answer.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Do you know a paper/book that does shows the equivalence of both problems in more detail? I still can't wrap my head around the second direction (from the asked to the reduced problem).

Comment: @McLawrence Not specifically; I seem to recall that the Oriented Matroids book I mentioned in a previous comment contains this argument somewhere in the first two chapters, in reference to a duality (before it begins talking explicitly about matroids) - but it can be a bit difficult to get one's hands on that book. If it's helpful, you can also express the equivalence succinctly by saying "A map from a space $S$ into $\mathbb R^k$ is the same as choosing $k$ maps $S\rightarrow\mathbb R$ for the coordinates" where "map" means linear here.

Comment: @MiloBrandt The part that I do not understand is this: "The kernel of each $f_i$ will be the image of the hyperplanes $x_i=0$ under $\pi$ and each cell will be the projection of a quadrant." What is $x_i$ in your description. It is not in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but in $S$, right? Is this a basis direction of the hyperplane?

Comment: @McLawrence I edited that paragraph; I think it was confusing and there were some typos. I think it might be clearer now - especially the important point that wasn't restated before: $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.