# Which quadrants can a codimension 3 subspace intersect?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, matroids

I am given 3 linearly independent vectors $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and I would like to understand which quadrants the orthogonal complement of their span intersects (depending on the coefficients of $x,y,z$). What is the best way to think about this? Any pointers are appreciated.

I've seen at the answers of an other question ([What is the maximum number of quadrants in $n$ dimensional space that a $k$ dimensional hyperplane can pass through?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887759/722603)) that matroids will likely have something to do with this. What are some good introductory writings on matroids?

Answer (score 1):

The comments in the linked question are suggesting not just matroids, but *oriented matroids*. The standard reference is [Björner et al. Oriented Matroids](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/oriented-matroids/A34966F40E168883C68362886EF5D334), but the text is not introductory as it assumes familiarity with matroids. I do not know of any introductory text on oriented matroids, however the material does not have a steep learning curve once you get familiar with (ordinary) matroids.

An introductory text on matroids is [Gordon and McNulty, Matroids: A geometric Introduction.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/matroids-a-geometric-introduction/2DCAB3A148C84F5DB32E1E398AD7A6FD)

The standard references on matroids are [Oxley, Matroid Theory](https://academic.oup.com/book/34846), [Welsh, Matroid Theory](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486474399.html) and [White, Theory of Matroids](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/theory-of-matroids/5A10C0830A709629F2845A95691780AB).